# Is there an IOS notification or callback that gets called when an app is installed?

Tags: ios

I'd like to do some setup at install time but am not sure if there's an event IOS sends to me when my app is installed.

What I'm trying to do is download some seed data so that when the user first launches my app for the first time it wont be empty.  I guessed there might be something in `UIApplication` but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do some sort of setup at, and *only at* **first launch**, then just use `NSUserDefaults`!

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstLaunch"]){
        [self performSelector:@selector(yourSetupView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

    }          

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In this case, when the user runs the app for the very first time, `yourSetupView` appears after a very very small delay.

Comment: Thanks **first launch** is an option but I'd prefer to do it even sooner (if that's possible).     
    
Would I put this code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?  I'm wishing there was an `application:didFinishInstalling:`.

Comment: Well you can't start the setup with the app closed :) So, the user launches the app, splash screen appears and then setup appears. 
I have that method in the `viewDidLoad` of the main window in my app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though I was hoping for a different one :)